# Can we deploy JavaFX app with Hibernate to .exe using Jpackage?

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, jpackage

so I've developed JavaFX App with Hibernate connection to database. And then I want to deploy it into .exe application using Jpackage. Is it possible or no? I've trying to search about this topic online but didn't found any clue. Thanks

Comment: Should be possible from a technical standpoint. What happens if you try?